# URL traffic from two different locations

Tags: proxy, pac

Need help to bypass URL traffic from two different locations
If connected to office network then go through proxy IP and if connected from outside then go through direct net.

Example as tried
if ( shExpMatch(url,"155.0.0.0:8888") || shExpMatch(url,"155.0.0.0:8888"))
return "PROXY 10.0.0.0:9443";
else
return "DIRECT";